# Connect to dev server in Flask for unittest

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write unittests for my Flask API endpoints. I want the test cases to connect to the dev server which is running on a different port 5555.

Here is what I am doing in `setUp()` to make a `test_client`.

```
import flask_app 
flask_app.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost/mvp_test_db'
flask_app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
flask_app.app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '192.168.2.2' //the IP of the dev server
flask_app.app.config['SERVER_PORT'] = 5555
self.app_client = flask_app.app.test_client()
```

Then when I make a request using `app_client` like -

```
r = self.app_client.post('/API/v1/dummy_api', data = {'user_id' : 1})
```

I get a 404 when I print `r` and the request never comes to the dev server (no logs printed). I am not able to inspect the URL to which the connection is being attempted above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It (app.test_client) does not send requests through network interfaces. All requests are simulated. These are processed inside werkzeug routing system. To process "/API/v1/dummy_api" url you need register a view for. If it is registered, connect it in the import section. Application settings and test settings almost always have almost equal settings.